# is there any one one correspondence between an empty set and set of natural number $\Bbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

Actually, I wants to know that how an empty set is finite.

If it's finite then it must have one to one correspondence to the segment of natural number.

Comment: See [Finite set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set): Formally, a set $S$ is called finite if there exists a bijection $f: S \to \{ 1,2,\ldots, n \}$ for some natural number n. The number n is the set's cardinality, denoted as $|S|$. The empty set is considered finite, with cardinality zero."

Comment: But we can use different definitions, like [Tarski'one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set#Other_concepts_of_finiteness): in this case we can prove that the empty set is finite (instead of assuming it as a convention).

Answer (score 7):

The empty set *is* a segment of the natural numbers. It's the segment that contains *none* of them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is: given any set $S$, the empty map $\emptyset:\emptyset\to S$ is injective. If you want to go the "in bijection with an inital segment of $\Bbb N$" route, then the empty map is surjective if and only if $S=\emptyset$, and $\emptyset$ is an initial segment of $\Bbb N$ by all means.